# Workflow regex to match at least two comma

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, regex

I am trying to find if a column contains more than two **comma** in it.

I tried

```
If Variable: div matches regular expression /,[^,]*,/
    Set Variable: test to more than two
Else
    Set Variable: test to only one
```

But it always sets variable to "only one". What am I missing?

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/([^,]*,[^,]*){3}/` or `/([^,]*,[^,]*){2,}/` (this one expresses business logic a bit better, explicitly saying '2 or more times')

PS: https://regex101.com/ might be useful to test those

---

Update: My bad, I forgot to mention you usually don't need to put regex in `/` in .NET.

A screenshot from that [awesome article in MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2008/05/14/create-compact-and-powerful-conditions-in-your-workflows/):
[image]

Comment: No luck. see my update

Comment: @Keerthi can you try without `/`'s?